# Insert name of image into database

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to insert img name into database.

```
<img class="modal-trigger" href="#modal1" src="img\test.png" onclick="getName()" id="img1" />
```

I am getting name of image using Javascript and also inserting into database in angularJS.

```
   var dept;
   function getName() {
     var fullPath = document.getElementById("img1").src;
     dept = fullPath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');

    document.getElementById("result").value = dept;
 } 
    $scope.addnew = function() {
        $http.post('addtodb.php',{'username' : $scope.username, 'dept' : $scope.dept}
        ).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        });
    }
```

Getting name of image works fine when I 'echo' it and also adding into database works cause I can add username. But how can I send dept variable into function addnew and put it into database?

Comment: this is an angular question, not php, plz don't tag irelevant stuff

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `dept = fullPath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '')` with
`$scope.dept = fullPath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '')`. 
Or Since you need the `getName()` function to run before `$scope.addNew()`, you could call the `$scope.addNew()` function after the `getName()` and pass in the `dept` as an argument. 
For instance:
Inside the function `getName()`, you call `$scope.addNew(dept)` and access the argument using `$scope.addnew = function(dept)`.

Comment: When you pass the variable `dept` as an argument like `$scope.addNew(dept)`, you will need to modify the post request to use the argument passed in. Like:  `$http.post('addtodb.php',{'username' : $scope.username, 'dept' : dept}
        )`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/dUA05xjs still nothing I get empty record from dept

Comment: Try this:
`var dept;
   function getName() {
     var fullPath = document.getElementById("img1").src;
     dept = fullPath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');

    document.getElementById("result").value = dept;
    $scope.addnew(dept);
 } 
    $scope.addnew = function(dept) {
        
        $http.post('addtodb.php',{'username' : $scope.username, 'dept' : dept} ).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

        });
    }`

Comment: Nothing maybe should I add something to  <img

Comment: I think the `<img>` tag is fine for what you want, however, verify that the value of the element with `id="result"` is being changed to the name of the image file when the image is clicked. If that happens then the value of dept is being set within the `getName()` function scope and hence should also be available to the `$scope.addnew()` function if passed in as an argument. Otherwise, if the value of the element is not being changed then there's an issue with the `<img>` tag.